# Virtual network for BizSpark team members

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I set up 2 virtual machines on 2 BizSpark accounts (team members). One is for a web application and another for PostgreSQL database. Currently I connect to the Postgres server via public IP address. Is there a way to set up virtual network between the 2 servers on different accounts/subscriptionIds using the new Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual networks do not span subscriptions (regardless of subscription type). You can still set up IP filtering on the input endpoints (or inbound network security rules, for ARM-based deployments) to only allow traffic from your source web application, since traffic is coming from a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also setup Vnet based Site to Site VPN between the 2 Virtual networks.
Here is some guidance : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/

Answer (score 1):

I saw two solutions for that that you can use in your case:

1) PaaS instead of IaaS

2) If VPN is absolutely mandatory, some of BizSpark startups are using OpenVPN for a few subscriptions and it works.